# Getting the Libname from the Teradata Schema

Tags: database, sas, schema, teradata

I am using SAS in connection to Teradata. 
There we have sometime the case that the Database name is needed in different Formats.

When I write SAS Code i use the Databasename/Libref like: SHORTLIB

And when i use Teradata code then I have the Scheme which looks like this: SCHEMA_A_B_C_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0

So how can I get the Libref from the Teradata SCHEMA?

Thank you.

Comment: Try using dictionary.columns or dictionary.tables to get the libref, as far I Know there is no way you can get libname from a Teradata schema

Comment: Are you trying to determine the SAS libref from Teradata? Can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: @mimi - can you share your libname statement?  This will tell us whether the schema is stored locally or in metadata.  If metadata, it should be possible to determine this using a metadata query and checking the library associations with matching schema property.  If locally, Stu's suggestion about `dictionary.libnames` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1.

`libname _all_ list;`

This will show you all currently assigned libraries in the log.

2.

```
proc sql;
    select *
    from dictionary.libnames;
quit;
```

This will also show you all currently assigned libraries with some different information that may be relevant.

Comment: Is there also a possibility for not assigned Libraries? For the most cases this answer would solve my problem.

Comment: Do you mean libraries assigned in metadata automatically, but are not pre-assigned?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the libref that you created you can query the DICTIONARY tables (or equivalent SASHELP views) to find the information on the schema that the libref is pointing to.

You can look at the SASHELP.VLIBNAM view the variables you need to reference are: LIBNAME ENGINE PATH SYSVALUE SYSNAME.

So the record with LIBNAME equal to your libref and SYSNAME equal to 'Schema/User' should be the one you want.  The schema name will be in the SYSVALUE variable.

Here is a link to SAS macro that will make this query totally in macro code and return the information in macro variables.

https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/dblibchk.sas